# Android - Creating a folder in the data/data/pkg/files directory

Tags: android, file, create-directory

Referencing this question:

[How to create files hierarchy in Androids '/data/data/pkg/files' directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1889188/how-to-create-files-hierarchy-in-anroids-data-data-pkg-files-directory)

What kind of a solution is there to this problem using the built in standard Java libraries, how do I navigate to the data/data/pkg directory and create folders and files in there?  Maybe using some of the Android calls where possible?

When a user uses my app I wish to save any files associated with that user in a folder pkg/files/username, so that I can easily read these folders later.  My other option is include the username in the filename but this isn't a very suitable and clean method in my opinion.

Comment: I don't understand what your question is - the question you link to has the answer already. All you need to do is create the "username" directory.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

getContext().getDir() method is your friend

```
File dir = ctx.getDir("my_sub_dir", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
File newfile = new File(topDirFile.getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + "new_file_name");
newfile.createNewFile();
BufferedOutputStream fout = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(newfile), 16 * 1024);
```

Comment: Once I've created the directory using that, how do I access it using openFileOutput() ?  Would it not just throw an exception?

Comment: getDir() returns a File instance. from there you can get use getDir(DIR, ACCESS).getAbsolutePath() + "/" + "file"  to get the actual file path and then just use FileInputStream

Comment: I get an exception whenever I try and do a getDir() for files/username, saying there is a path seperator... how am I supposed to create a directory where I want it without using a path seperator?