# How to put file into '/data/data/pkg/files' directory?

Tags: android, file, file-io, storage

I have a txt-file, that I want to put into above mentioned folder in order to read it and transmit. While connecting a phone as a storage I can not find this folder. 
I assume, that this directory is created, when program executes, right. So . Is there a way how to read from internal storage already created(not by app) file?

Comment: Try this :

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5486623/android-creating-a-folder-in-the-data-data-pkg-files-directory

Comment: This is **not a duplicate** of the linked questions.  Those concern creating files from an application itself, while this question seeks to create a file in an app's storage area using a connected PC.