# Android : how to create dir to ..../PackageNameFolder and copy files to It programmatically (KOTLIN)

Tags: android, kotlin, storage, data-access

sorry for my bad english

i have tried so much to create a directory in
data/data/pkg/
or
sdcard/storage/0/Android/data/pkg/

in Kotlin

i tried :

[Android - Creating a folder in the data/data/pkg/files directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5486623/android-creating-a-folder-in-the-data-data-pkg-files-directory)

https://www.tabnine.com/code/java/methods/android.content.Context/getExternalFilesDir

https://www.tabnine.com/code/java/methods/android.content.Context/getFilesDir

/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/

i have these permissions in my manifest:

```
uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
```

Comment: Post the code you tried. Do away with all these links.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
String fileName = "FILE_NAME";
String filePath = context.getExternalFilesDir("FOLDER_NAME").toString()+"/"+fileName;
FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(filePath);
```

**Example:** Save Bitmap in internal storage

```
public static void downloadToInternalStorage(Context context, Bitmap bitmap) throws IOException {
    String fileName = "image.jpg";
    String filePath = context.getExternalFilesDir("images").toString()+"/"+fileName;

    FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(filePath);
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fileOutputStream);
    fileOutputStream.flush();
    fileOutputStream.close();
}
```

**In Kotlin**

```
@kotlin.jvm.Throws(IOException::class)
fun downloadToInternalStorage(context: Context?, bitmap: Bitmap) {
    val fileName = "image.jpg"
    val filePath: String = context.getExternalFilesDir("images").toString().toString() + "/" + fileName
    val fileOutputStream = FileOutputStream(filePath)
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fileOutputStream)
    fileOutputStream.flush()
    fileOutputStream.close()
}
```

Comment: You are only creating files. That is not what has been asked.

Comment: you can follow same approach to copy files

Comment: Did you read what OP is asking for? It starts with 'how to create a directory?'.

Comment: yeah he asked, how to create dir and also how to copy files to it, the solution I've posted does both

Comment: You mean with context.getExternalFilesDir("images"). Indeed. You are right. Sorry for confusion. (I was only looking for a mkdir() or mkdirs()).